# How to know if a string is already escaped special with special characters?

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, decoding

I have this URL:

```
"http://www.somedomain.com/folder/مرحبا المستخدم.jpg"
```

So I needs to escape these Arabic values else it will not able to create `URL` object.

I am doing it like this,

```
let originalString = "http://www.somedomain.com/folder/مرحبا المستخدم.jpg"
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

This will be the output of `escapedString`:

`http://www.somedomain.com/folder/%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85.jpg`

So far so good. But when I force to try to escape an already escaped URL then the result is weird.

How to check if a string is already encoded?

Comment: @Hermang: why are you trying to double-escape this string in the first place?

Comment: @DerekBrown, I am not sure, if I am doing it? Can you please tell me more on this.

Comment: There is *no way* to decide if `%2B` is the (already percent-encoded) "+" string, or the string "%2B" which must be encoded as `%252B%`. You should know if your strings are percent-encoded or not.

Comment: @MartinR yes and no- if you make the assumption that no **correct** url includes a percent sign, you could just check for the presence of the percent sign.  Obviously this is a problem if you have non-url-safe files (as in the example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it smoothly:

```
extension String {
    func isEscaped() -> Bool {
        return self.removingPercentEncoding != self
    }
}
```

then

```
let yourEscapedString = "http://www.somedomain.com/folder/%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%AF%D9%85.jpg"
print(yourEscapedString.isEscaped()) // true

let yourNotEscapedString = "http://www.somedomain.com/folder/مرحبا المستخدم.jpg"
print(yourNotEscapedString.isEscaped()) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but might be work.

You can check your URL is valid or not, If Its valid then no need to escaping agin if not then you should escape it.

Like check URL is valid or not

```
func isValidMyURL (_ urlString: NSString) -> Bool {
    let urlRegEx = "((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx).evaluateWithObject(urlString)
}
```

And then

```
if !isValidMyURL(originalString) { // If not valid then escape it
    let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
}
```

Other wise directly use `escapedString`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this, but I would try to 'unescape' the original string first, and then compare the result with the original string. If they match, there was no escaping in the original string.  If they don't match, the original string was escapeds already.